# Logic behind camel ServicePool when used with Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, apache-camel

I have a camel instance with a Netty endpoint that consolidates many incoming requests to send to a single receiver.  More specifically, this is a web service whereby each incoming SOAP request results in a `Producer.sendBody()` into the camel subsystem.  The processing of each request involves different routes, but they will all end up in the single Netty endpoint to send on to the next-level server.  All is fine, as long as I only have a handful of incoming requests at any one time.  If I start having more than 100 simultaneous requests, though, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:71) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.add(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:209) [na:1.6.0_24]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultServicePool.release(DefaultServicePool.java:95) [camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.done(ProducerCache.java:297) ~[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2$1.done(SendProcessor.java:120) ~[camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.handlers.ClientChannelHandler.messageReceived(ClientChannelHandler.java:162) ~[camel-netty-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.3.1.Final.jar:na]
```

This is coming from the `DefaultServicePool` that's used by the Netty component.  The `DefaultServicePool` uses an `ArrayBlockingQueue` as the backend to the queue and it sets it to a default capacity of 100 Producers.  It uses a service pool for performance reasons, to avoid having to keep creating and destroying often-reused producers.  Fair enough.  Unfortunately, I'm not getting the logic on how it is implemented.

This all starts in `ProducerCache::doInAsyncProducer`, which starts off by calling `doGetProducer`.  Said method attempts to `acquire` a Producer from the pool and, if that fails, it creates a new Producer using `endpoint.getProducer()`.  It then makes sure that the service pool exists using `pool.addAndAcquire`.  That done, it returns to the calling function.  The `doInAsyncProducer` does its thing until it's finished, in which case it calls the `done` processor.  At this point, we're completely done processing the exchange, so it releases the Producer back to the pool using `pool.release`

Here is where the rubber hits the road.  The `DefaultServicePool::release` method inserts the Producer into the `ArrayBlockingQueue` backend using an `add`.  This is where my `java.lan.IllegalStateException` is coming from.

Why?  Well, let's look through a use case.  I have 101 simultaneous incoming requests.  Each of them hits the Netty endpoint at roughly the same time.  The very first creates the service pool with the capacity of 100 but it's empty to start.  In fact, each of the 101 requests will create a new Producer from the `endpoint.getProducer`; each will verify that they don't exceed the capacity of the service pool (which is empty); and each will continue on to send to the server.  After each finishes, it tries to do a `pool.release`.  The first 100 will succeed, since the pool capacity hasn't been reached.  The 101st request will attempt to add to the queue and will fail, since the queue is full!

Is that right?  If I'm reading that correctly, then this code will always fail whenever there are more than 100 simultaneous requests.  My service needs to support upwards of 10,000 simultaneous requests, so that's just not going to fly.

It seems like a more stable solution might be to:

1. Pre-allocate all 100 Producers on initialization
2. Block during `acquire` until a Producer is available
3. Absolutely do not create your own non-pool Producers if using a ServicePool

In the meantime, I'm thinking of throttling incoming requests.

What I'm hoping for with this question is to learn if I'm reading that logic correctly and to see if it can get changed.  Or, am I using it wrong?  Is there a better way to handle this type of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the logic should IMHO be improved. I have logged a ticket to improve this.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5703